Injected resources blocked from external scripts with `strict-dynamic` and `nonces`
I'm attempting to implement a CSP for a client and am running into some difficulties:

I have a script for Google Translate being pulled in

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" nonce="0190369b-35c3-4474-b31e-46e09bf5552c"></script>


I have a CSP that includes


a nonce value
strict-dynamic
some hashes (these are inline styles that have been sha256'd)

default-src * data: ;
 script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-bc138385-6e60-4e78-8e12-c516b9835ccf' ;
 style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'nonce-bc138385-6e60-4e78-8e12-c516b9835ccf' 'sha256-<someHash>' ;


Console Error for :

Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://www.gstatic.com/_/translate_http/_/ss/k=translate_http.tr.26tY-h6gH9w.L.W.O/am=DAY/d=0/rs=AN8SPfrCcgxoBri2FVMQptvuOBiOsolgBw/m=el_main_css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-bc138385-6e60-4e78-8e12-c516b9835ccf'  'sha256-...' ". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.


Console Error for injected inline style

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-bc138385-6e60-4e78-8e12-c516b9835ccf'  'sha256-...'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-JIj2SxE0HcsALEzIeYfM7TQkcz/B/Cfoc4ARmAXL5Ck='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I've tried to get an integrity hash for the original script, but it google doesn't provide one. I've tried to generate the hash, but the request is not cors enabled (on googles side) so it cannot use the integrity attribute.
I've tried adding the domain (gstatic.com) to my allowlist, but cannot do so since I'm using strict-dynamic.
My understanding is that, given my script with src="translate.google.com" has a nonce that is in my CSP, it should be able to load resources and inject them.
There are also <link> tags that are having issues, such as
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/grj3fwu.css">


I have a nonce on this  element that exists in my style-src directive.
It pulls in a number of different styles through an @import, such as for "https://p.typekit.net/p.css"
It has a different URL, so even if I put the original use.typekit.net in my allowlist, this secondary @import fails it. I can add p.typekit.net to my allowlist, but this domain changes and I have no control over it.

Is there anything similar to strict-dynamic for <link> elements / style-src directive?

Even though script and style have many similarities in CSP, strict-dynamic is only for scripts. The potential threats by script are much bigger than those of styles, which are well covered in https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.
As you've locked down scripts thoroughly with strict-dynamic and nonce, you can be more lenient with styles, especially if you lock down the remainder of your CSP to prevent exfiltration. In that case adding *.typekit.net to style-src would probably be acceptable in most threat models.
If there are a low number of injected inline styles, add the suggested hashes from the console errors.
If you can't get the hash of an external file, try downloading it and get the checksum. If it is not a versioned script and may change, do host based allowlisting instead.

Thank you for clarifying strict-dynamic, I misread and didn't realize you could do wildcards subdomains - that will help a lot.
"try downloading it and get the checksum" - could you clarify what this means?
Does this mean download the file and compute the SHA + base64?
Thank you!

Yes, download and hash as sha356/384/512 from UTF-8, then convert to base64. Alternatively you could add an incorrect integrity attribute on the script tag and the browser might compute it for you in the console error. Example: 